# how to create MVC project in .net core 1.0 with entity framework core 1.0

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

Guys please help me creating a project with CRUD operation

I read the documentation of Microsoft. It creates by default with Local DB.

It automatically does all the CRUD operation. I have no clue.

Please explain in detail with other Database.

is there any best tutorial to read for Core 1.0 ( Apart from microsoft)

I prefer PostgreSql

Comment: You can check out NPGSQL http://www.npgsql.org/doc/index.html. You can use it with EF Core of you like

Comment: I want to use it with EF core only